Read multiple .bib files and Add filename as new column in R
I have more than 200 .bib files from WoS that I would like to analize with bibliometrix package. But each file refers to a different specific place that I'm working about. I would like to read those multiple files, adding the filename (which is the places' name) as a new column for identification while joining all the files into a unique object (with the column with filename identifying them). I've been trying some alternatives, but cannot succeed.
This is what I've been trying:
library(RefManageR)
library(bibliometrix)

    # List of .bib files
files <- list.files(path = "C:/Users/drive/OneDrive/Documentos/cienciometria parques africanos", pattern = "\\.bib$", full.names = TRUE)

# Function to read a single .bib file and add the column with the file name
read_bib <- function(file) {
  bib <- ReadBib(file)
  bib$file_source <- basename(file)  # Add column with file name
  return(bib)
}

# Read all .bib files and add the column with the file name
bib_list <- lapply(files, read_bib)

# Combine all BibEntry objects into a single one
combined_bib <- do.call("c", bib_list)

But when I run tha lapply I get this error:
Error in seq.default(1, guess_eoentry) : 'to' must be a finite number
Additionally: There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)


Is bib a data.frame? What is the output of class(bib)?

The bib object does not exist because lapply does not complete the created function. but the imported files are WoS files in .bib format. Is there any other way to do this? I mean, import the multiples files, add the filename as id column when joining all the files into one dataframe?

The return value of ReadBib is not data.frame.Try something like files[1] |> ReadBib() |> str() |> capture.output(file = "bibenrty.txt") and see what ReadBib returns in the output text file bibentry.txt..

Actually I've changed the code, and it's working but not to all files. I have 234 .bib files, and my output df comes with information about only 93 of them. df <- data.frame() for(i in files){   y = ReadBib(i)   for(j in 1:length(y)){     data = y[[j]]     data = data.frame(data)     data$sourceFile = basename(i)     df = bind_rows(df,data)   } }
